# Theoretical CS Birthday Celebration?

Tags: discussion

Did you know the Theoretical Computer Science SE's birthday is coming up on **November 30th**? Congratulations!

How about a contest or some other fun activity to stir things up a little? After a year of great Q&A, **we'd like the opportunity to "give back" for everyone's hard work.**

Anniversary events area a great way to spark some interest in the extracurricular activity in your site (more meta participation). An “anniversary event" can be just about anything. Take a look at [**Super User’s 2nd Birthday Super Contest**](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/08/19/super-users-2nd-birthday-super-contest/) for inspiration. It doesn’t have to be a contest. Dream up whatever *you* feel the community will find interesting, and go for it.

Start a meta post or chat event to work out the details. Rally support for your event and bring it to our attention (community@stackexchange.com). We're really interested in community-lead initiatives, so let’s just say, if you can work out the details, we’re very motivated to say “go for it!”

Comment: Note that we already had a [celebration](http://cstheory.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/happy-birthday-cstheory/) on the blog when it was one year from the start of the private beta.

Comment: The more celebrations the better, as long as we have cake :)

Comment: The Cake is a Lie!

Answer (score 9):

Suggestion: cstheory T-Shirt for our cstheory bloggers and editors.

Comment: Do the blog editors get one too?

Comment: @Joe, we can add that to the suggestion.

Comment: That was meant a bit tongue in cheek!

Comment: How about for the moderators as well!?

Comment: Could they be available for purchase for other people that aren't bloggers or editors? Or make a special t-shirt for bloggers and editors and regular people for purchase?

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps we could have an essay contest on some topic in TCS (maybe surprising results or open problems etc. or in Rumsfeldise it "Known knowns, known unknowns and unknown unknowns"),  with submissions posted on the blog and voting on meta.

If that was the case, we would need to come up with a suitable prize though.

Comment: Joe, we have two weeks till the anniversary, so if we are going to do this we should add more details to this. What is the time frame for this? Are we going to have them in a two weeks or is it going to continue till some specified date? Is voting on meta a good or should we use something else (like number of views, I think part of the idea of an anniversary is to celebrate but another part is to further promote the site/blog).

Comment: about the prizes, I don't know how big is the budget, on SuperUser the value of maximum prize was $250. In that respect I think a reasonable choice can be a book that the winner will choose (with some caps on the price). Or based on the budget I think an ebook reader (or something similar) might also be reasonable. But before discussing the prize we should focus on other details of the contest.

Comment: @Kaveh: Yes I think something like that would be perfect. It certainly doesn't have to be too big.

Comment: To make the contest more Q&A focused, I would suggest that the topic restrictions involve something like "related to a popular/unanswered/etc question on cstheory". However, I doubt that 2 weeks is a suitable timeline. It will give a huge advantage to people that have pre-prepared essays and/or people who lurk on meta. Although this is good for rewarding existing users, it is not as good for attracting new users or engaging non-regular users. Further, how would we have enough time to post all the submissions and wait for votes? If we post all submissions on the same day it will awkward...

Comment: I would think that we should start accepting submissions from the anniversary for some fixed period of time.

Comment: we should also make sure people use a specific tag to mark their submissions ?

Comment: @Suresh: Do you mean on the blog?

Comment: No I meant on the site itself

Comment: @Suresh: I don't quite follow. How would one submit an essay via the site?

Comment: oh never mind. I was confused. yes, submitting on the blog and tagging as such would be the plan

Comment: re kavehs comment any idea or more detail on how SuperUser got a $250 prize or budget for prizes? re suresh's comment, it would be very useful if there was a place/section for possible blogs to be submitted & rated & edited collaboratively etc, but unf. TCS meta is probably not the place (current atmosphere is restrictive).. maybe a stackexchange architecture chg or feature addition to discuss with them re their blogs (which are themselves rather new to stackexchange)..

Comment: @JoeFitzsimons Hi Joe, please apologize for this off-topic comment ... Some people are preparing to some kind of revive TP.SE with a slightly broadend scope outside the SE network. We have already quite successfully tested importing the content of the TP data dump into a Q2A offline site on private laptops (some technical issues have still to be resolved though). Concerning hosting, we will probably try this. Not sure if you and other former TP.SE users would be interested (?), but you can find us [here](http://tpproposal.wordpress.com/) or mail to dilatoproton@googlemail.com

Comment: Whoops, I meant this hosting: https://www.digitalocean.com/